# Why am I crashing when trying to create a weak reference to self while dealloc is happening on another thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c

## Background

Our app has a class that attempts to implement the [Receptionist Pattern for KVO observation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ReceptionistPattern/ReceptionistPattern.html).  Other classes throughout the app (such as view controllers) create instances of this one Receptionist class to serve as the KVO observer.  Each Receptionist instance keeps a copy of a block provided by the owner, which the Receptionist instance will invoke on the proper operation queue when a KVO notification arrives.

The Receptionist's dealloc method invokes the KVO removeObserver method.  The Owner keeps the Receptionist instance as a strong-reference field, so when the Owner is deallocated, the Receptionist will remove itself as an observer in the process of being deallocated.

## The Crash

We're seeing reports from the field of crashes when the KVO notification is received by a Receptionist instance on one thread while the same instance's dealloc is in progress on another thread.  The Receptionist's implementation of  observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: is crashing on this line:

```
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
```

The stack trace in the crash report shows this as a call to objc_initWeak, which calls weak_register_no_lock, which calls _objc_fatal.

The object whose key is being observed by this particular Receptionist is never deallocated.  The Owner is also not being deallocated; the Owner is replacing this Receptionist instance with a different one.

## The Confusion

I can understand that it's not useful to create a weak reference to an object that's already being deallocated, but I would expect weakSelf to receive a nil value, not to cause a crash.

The [documentation for objc_initWeak](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#arc-runtime-objc-initweak) explicitly mentions setting the target to null if the argument to which the reference is desired has begun deallocation.  That sounds like the desired behavior, but I don't think it's what I'm seeing.  I'm not keen to replace that line with an explicit call to objc_initWeak, since I doubt I'd manage the deallocation properly.

Could it really be the Receptionist's responsibility to notice that its own deallocation is in progress before requesting a weak reference to self?   I would assume that there's some window between when an NSObject's deallocation starts and when that object's dealloc method is called, so signalling within the object from the dealloc method sounds flaky.

Thank you for reading!

PS: heavily edited after reading the questions raised by Ken Thomases.

Comment: So each Receptionist instance contains strong reference to its observed object, this reference assigned during initialization without dispatches to another threads, 'addObserver:' also called during initialization without dispatches to another threads, and 'removeObserver:' called during deallocation?

Comment: @SergeyAlpeev Yes all around.  I confirmed that the Receptionist's reference to the observed object is strong and is populated during the Receptionist's init.  The addObserver: also happens during Receptionist's init.  removeObserver: is called in dealloc.  One questionable smell not previously noticed: properties are all initialized (before addObserver) with self.x = x instead of _x = x.  Still seems unlikely to be the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the creation of the weak reference. The line you cite should only be run in a context where something has a strong reference to `self`.

Think about it: the crash that you're seeing may be during that line within your `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` implementation, but, since there's clearly a race between deallocation and the call of that method, the deallocation could also occur during dispatch of that method call (or some other point). You're vulnerable to different crashes. So, no changes to the implementation of the method could possibly fix the problem, since the problem could manifest before your method is even called.

It's your responsibility to keep a strong reference to an object if you're going to be calling methods on that object. Or, from the other perspective, to avoid calling methods on object pointers that you're not sure will live for the duration of the call (because you hold a strong reference or some other API guarantee).

With KVO, you need to remove observers before releasing your last strong reference.

Comment: Your point about the rest of the method is valid, but so long as self is nil, it won't crash.  Half the reason we have receptionists is so that observer removal is automatically handled as part of the ARC deallocation.  I really have trouble with the idea of the owner needing to warn the receptionist that it's about to be deallocated.  The [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html) explicitly say "A typical pattern is to...unregister during deallocation (usually in dealloc)".

Comment: Under what circumstances could `self` be nil? How would you have gotten into the method in the first place? Observer removal is not automatically handled. The same docs you cite say "An observer does not automatically remove itself when deallocated. The observed object continues to send notifications, oblivious to the state of the observer. However, a change notification, like any other message, sent to a released object, triggers a memory access exception. You therefore ensure that observers remove themselves before disappearing from memory."

Comment: I don't know what object you consider the "owner". Whatever object added the observer is generally what's responsible for a) keeping a strong reference to the observer and probably the observed object; and b) removing the observer before releasing the strong reference to it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!  I've edited the question with the hope of answering your questions, but I will repeat here for readability.  Receptionist is a class used dozens of places in our app to simplify KVO.  Each Owner creates a Receptionist instance for each variable Owner wishes to observe.  Each Receptionist is kept as a strong reference by Owner, so Receptionist will be deallocated automatically if Owner is deallocated.  Receptionist's dealloc method invokes removeObserver.  The problem is not that Receptionist hasn't removed itself as an observer; that happens at the end of dealloc.